# Multiple pair-wise string comparisons in R

Tags: r

I am trying to evaluate if the value of one (string) variable matches those in multiple other (string) variables in an R dataframe. If there is at least one valid match, I would like to return True; if not, I would like to return False.

Consider this toy dataframe:

```
toydf<-data.frame(
  base1=c("DOG","CAT","MOUSE"),
  base2=c("FISH","RAT","BUNNY"),
  target=c("DOG","HORSE","BUNNY"),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

    base1 base2 target
  1   DOG  FISH    DOG
  2   CAT   RAT  HORSE
  3 MOUSE BUNNY  BUNNY
```

I want to compare the values in *target* with those in both *base1* and *base2* and return *TRUE* if there is at least one match, and *FALSE* otherwise:

```
    base1 base2 target check
  1   DOG  FISH    DOG  TRUE
  2   CAT   RAT  HORSE FALSE
  3 MOUSE BUNNY  BUNNY  TRUE
```

In this simple and small example, I know this can be easily achieved using:

```
toydf$check<-toydf$target==toydf$base1 | toydf$target==toydf$base2
```

However, in the actual dataset, I have a very large number of *base* variables against which to check for matches, so I'd like to avoid repeating these | statements.

I've attempted to achieve this using *%in%* but in order to do that, I first have to collect the values of *base1* and *base2* in a list or vector:

```
toydf$baseall<-apply(toydf[1:2],1,function(x) list(x))
toydf$check<-toydf$target %in% toydf$baseall
```

However, this returns a vector with all values to *FALSE*. I suspect this has something to do with the way the list is created in the dataframe, but I am not sure how to solve this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to match ANY target, or only the target in the corresponding row?

Comment: Only those in the corresponding row.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possibility:

```
toydf$check <- as.logical(rowSums(toydf==toydf$target)-1)
#> toydf
#  base1 base2 target check
#1   DOG  FISH    DOG  TRUE
#2   CAT   RAT  HORSE FALSE
#3 MOUSE BUNNY  BUNNY  TRUE
```

This code counts for each row of the dataframe the cases where an entry is equal to that specified in the column `toydf$target`. Since we did not exclude this target column from the dataframe, the sum is always at least one (the entry in the target column is obviously equal to itself), hence we need to correct this by subtracting 1. The result for each row is then converted into a Boolean `FALSE` or `TRUE` depending on whether the calculated value is zero (no entry in the other columns is equal to that in the `target` column) or not, respectively.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The above code works for the given test data, but when I change toydf$target to c("a", "b", "c"), I get FALSE, FALSE, TRUE for the results.  Not what is desired, I think.  Maybe:

Comment: This is very elegant, but it uses the entire toydf as the argument in apply. That works in my example (so that's on me!), but in reality, there will be other, non-relevant variables in the dataframe as wel, against which I don't want to compare. Subsettting toydf in your example by `toydf[1:2]` does not seem to work.

Comment: @ralm Please check the updated version. You can subset `toydf` by removing columns on the right hand side which are not of interest.

Comment: @Rick The revised version should now work correctly. I have no explanation for the odd behavior that you described, and which I could reproduce with the former code.

Answer (score 0):

```
# how about:
bool <- apply(toydf[,1:2], 2, FUN = "%in%", toydf$target)
toydf$check <- apply(bool, 1, any)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, could you walk me through what is happening here?

Comment: Sorry, a bit too quick there, I think I got it. First you construct a matrix with Boolean values that compares _target_ to the first two columns in _toydf_. Then you create a vector/variable that returns _TRUE_ if any of the Boolean values (row-wise) is _TRUE_. Correct? Very nice!

Comment: But my code looks for matches anywhere in toydf$target.  If you just want to check the corresponding row of toydf$target, then I like the code from RHertel above. (or my own version, derived from it of: apply(toydf[,1:2] == toydf$target, 1, FUN = any)